# If/else condition in socket.io and HTTP node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to implement a conditional action for socket.io, using Node.js's HTTP package.

Basically what i want is, according to the get request, the socket.io to call different function or send different data.

Here is my code:

```
var http = require('http'),
fs = require('fs');

var app = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
fs.readFile("client.html", 'utf-8', function (error, data) {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    response.write(data);
    response.end();
});
}).listen(1337);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
socket.on('message_to_server', function(data) {

    http.get("/something", function(res) {
        io.sockets.emit("message_to_client",{ message: data["message"] });
        console.log(data["message"]);
    });

    http.get("/else", function(res) {
        console.log("something else");
    });

});
});
```

What should i do to implement such feature?

Comment: Currently you are getting both `something` and `else`. What should determine which get request to make?

Comment: You are mixing the two up: as it stands now - each time 'message_to_server' is sent, you are adding a http.get handler - neither of which is actually doing anything to send an HTTP response back.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are doing it in the wrong way.

It can be done like

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
   socket.on("something", function(res) {
        socket.emit("message_to_client",{ message: data["message"] });
        console.log(data["message"]);
   });

   socket.on("else", function(res) {
        console.log("something else");
   });
});
```

and edit the views for route `/something` so as to emit `something` when it loads to server. and do the same for route `/else`

Here you are emiting the custom events to the server according to the page you are in sothat that server can respond/emit accordingly to each route. The other way you are trying doesnt seem to work. Sorry if i am wrong.

#### update

in your client side (views) you could have like

view1.html

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
socket.on('connect', function(){
socket.emit('something');
});

socket.on('message_to_client', function (data) {
alert(data);
});
```

view2.html

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
socket.on('connect', function(){
socket.emit('else');
});

socket.on('message_to_client', function (data) {
alert(data);
});
```

#### note

also note that from server if you use `io.socket.emit` it would broadcast to all connections . instead use `socket.emit` (in your case object is `socket`) to send to the perticular connection

Comment: basically what i want to do is.. when i goto localhost/test.. socket io should give one type of data and when i goto localhost.test2 .. socket io should different data.

Comment: each page/route would render different html, so in that you would have the socket.js included and `connect` to socket.io server. then  `onload` of page you could emit a custom event according to the page you are in and the server can process them separately.

Comment: i use your code as you pasted above.. and in client side i did like http://pastebin.com/ewDU7DX1.. but it doesnt work.. is there something wrong?